# How to use SASS/ SCSS in Yii2?

Tags: sass, yii2

I want to use sass/scss in a new project, but it somehow doesn't work. 
I am using the yii2-asset-converter and when I try to convert the scss-file, the following error is thrown:

`Class @app/extensions/assetparser/vendors/phamlp/sass/SassParser does not exist`

I am checking the path ../phamlp/ and notice, that the Folder sass resp. SassParser.php doesn't exist. 
The SassParser.php is located in the extension  vendor/richthegeek/phpsass, which is required by yii2-asset-converter.

I have tried out some paths like:
`@ vendor/richthegeek/phpsass` or

```
__DIR__/../../vendor/richthegeek/phpsass
```

But it doesn't worked .After a lot of unsuccessful attempts I hope some of you know how to solve the problem.

PS:I use the advanced app template

Answer (score 5):

Don't use PhalmP or phpsass. These are outdated. You'll never get satisfactory results with them, especially when using modern Sass libraries.

Use original Sass as a standalone.

Simply install Ruby (you might already have it) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and use the `sass` command line tool to compile.

Also, using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) might make your life easier. Compass helps organizing your Sass code and also provides a Sass library with a lot of useful helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/nizsheanez/yii2-asset-converter).

But you must combine your sass code in single file.

Here's example of config/web.php

```
'assetManager'=>[
        'converter'=>[
            'class'=> 'nizsheanez\assetConverter\Converter',
            'force'=> true, // true : If you want convert your sass each time without time dependency
            'destinationDir' => '', //at which folder of @webroot put compiled files
            'parsers' => [
                'scss' => [ // file extension to parse
                    'class' => 'nizsheanez\assetConverter\Scss',
                    'output' => 'css', // parsed output file type
                    'options' => [ // optional options
                        'enableCompass' => true, // default is true
                        'importPaths' => ['/sass','/sass/_offers'], // import paths, you may use path alias here,
                        // e.g., `['@path/to/dir', '@path/to/dir1', ...]`
                        'lineComments' => true, // if true — compiler will place line numbers in your compiled output
                        'outputStyle' => 'expanded', // May be `compressed`, `crunched`, `expanded` or `nested`,
                        // see more at http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: This plugin also uses an outdated compiler